# Iterate through rows in a dataframe and change value of a column based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have a dataframe called *df* which looks like the one shown below:

```
Id      Place        
1        NY        
2       Berlin          
3       Paris        
4       Paris         
5       Berlin
```

And a dictionary, which has IDs as keys and places as values as shown below:

```
id_to_place = { 1 : "Berlin", 2: "Berlin", 3: "NY"}
```

I want to iterate through every row of the dataframe and see if the ID is contained in the *id_to_place* dictionary. If so, then I wanna replace the column *Place* of that row with the dictionary value. For instance after runninh the code I want the output to be:

```
Id      Place        
1       Berlin       
2       Berlin          
3       NY        
4       Paris         
5       Berlin
```

So far I have tried this code:

```
id_to_place = { 1 : "Berlin", 2: "Berlin", 3: "NY"}

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    id = row['id']
    place = row['place']
    for item in id_to_place:
        if item == str(id):
          df.loc[df.id =id,'place'] = id_to_place[item]

print(df)
```

But when I run the code the dataframe stays unchangable. Does anyone have an idea as to why this happens? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current method isn't working because your items in your dictionaries are integers and you're checking them against str(id) which always returns False. If you remove the str and just check item against id then it works.

```
id_to_place = { 1 : "Berlin", 2: "Berlin", 3: "NY"}

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    id = row['id']
    place = row['place']
    for item in id_to_place:
        if item == id: # this line changed
          df.loc[df.id =id,'place'] = id_to_place[item]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for replace matched values, then replace `NaN`s by original column by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Place'] = df['Id'].map(id_to_place).fillna(df['Place'])
print (df)
   Id   Place
0   1  Berlin
1   2  Berlin
2   3      NY
3   4   Paris
4   5  Berlin
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a DataFrame from your dict to just assign values in a vectorized way:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(id_to_place.values()), index=id_to_place.keys(),
           columns=['Place'])
df.set_index('Id', inplace=True)
df.loc[df1.index] = df1.Place
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```