# create new category column using pandas string contains and loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   name             Title
    abc          'Tech support'
    xyz          'UX designer'
    ghj          'Manager IT'
     ...            ....
```

I want to iterate through the data frame and using `df.str.contains` make another column that will categorize those jobs. There are 8 categories.

The output will be :

```
name              Title             category
abc           'Tech support'         'Support' 
xyz           'UX designer'          'Design'
ghj           'Manager IT'           'Management'
...              ....              ....
```

here's what I've tried so far:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if   df.Title[i].str.contains("Support"):
            df.category[i]=="Support"
    elif df.Title[i].str.contains("designer"):
            df.category[i]=="Design"
    else df.Title[i].str.contains("Manager"):
            df.category[i]=="Management"
```

of course , I'm a noob at programming and this throws the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-29-d9457f9cb172>", line 6
    else df.Title[i].str.contains("Manager"):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `else` should also be an `elif`

Comment: correct python syntax is `elif:` and `else:`. You forgot `:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
cat_dict = {"Support":"Support", "designer":"Designer", "Manager": "Management"}

df['category'] = (df['Title'].str.extract(fr"\b({'|'.join(cat_dict.keys())})\b")[0]
                    .map(cat_dict)
                 )
```

Comment: Can this implementation be made case sensitive?  ie, `Tech support` and `tech support` will be categorized as `Support` without adding another item to dictionary..

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami yes, just pass `re.IGNORECASE` to `extract`, i.e. `.str.extract("...", re.IGNORECASE)`.

Answer (score 1):

General syntax of python if statement is:

```
if test expression:
     Body of if
elif test expression:
     Body of elif
else: 
     Body of else
```

As you can see in the syntax, to evaluate a *test expression*, it should be in the *if* or in the *elif* construct. The code throws the syntax error as the test expression is placed in the *else* construct. Consider changing the last *else* to *elif* and add a fall back case for error like:

```
else:
    df.category[i]=="Others"
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer: [Iterate through rows and change value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187195/iterate-through-rows-in-a-dataframe-and-change-value-of-a-column-based-on-other) should get you going!

Lmk, if you have more questions!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
name             Title
abc          Tech support
xyz          UX designer
ghj          Manager IT
"""), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')

masks = [df.Title.str.lower().str.contains('support'),
    df.Title.str.lower().str.contains('designer'),
    df.Title.str.lower().str.contains('manager')
]

values = [
    'Support',
    'Design',
    'Management'
]

import numpy as np

df['Category'] = np.select(masks, values, default='Unknown')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  name         Title    Category
0  abc  Tech support     Support
1  xyz   UX designer      Design
2  ghj    Manager IT  Management
```

Comment: I get this error if I use your snippet. `TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray` in line `df['Category'] = np.select(masks, values, default='Unknown')`

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami Added full code. Could you please verify?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. :D